# how to Hazelcast jet JDBC continues source get data when new record insert or existing record updated in a database table?

Tags: jdbc, hazelcast-jet

about how to Hazelcast jet JDBC continues source get data when new record insert or existing record updated in a database table?

Comment: Starting your question with "please urgent help" and copy-pasting same statement twice doesn't make your question to look like something people are going to spend their spare time on.

Answer (score 0):

Nuri, one needs a CDC (Change data capture) tool to extract changes from the database. Hazelcast Jet comes with a set of CDC connectors: https://jet-start.sh/docs/tutorials/cdc

Another approach might be to use custom database triggers to extract and publish changes made on the database table. This is a poor man's solution to CDC but might work for low-volume scenarios.